# NPE ocurred when used `WebTestClient.mutateWith() ` in end to end tests

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux

When I wrote some tests for `webflux` applications. And I tried to add credentials via `mutateWith(mockUser().password("password"))` in `WebTestClient`, but it caused NPE thrown.

I used `bindToServer` to connect test client to the running remote APIs, and tried to use `mutateWith(mockUser().password("password"))` add basic authentication to the request. It throws a NPE when the tests.

**Updated Source codes**: https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/security-method/src/test/java/com/example/demo/IntegrationTests.java#L118-L127

Comment: could you copy/paste your code here and the complete stacktrace as well?

Comment: is seems it is my fault in the original codes, the `mutateWith(mockUser())` should only work in MockServer environment. I changed the codes  to use `mutate` to build the basic authentication manually, it caused the request is blocked till it is timeout.

Comment: so your issue is solved? don't hesitate to answer your own question then, this can help others.

Comment: @BrianClozel Thanks for your suggestion.  I have updated my original post, hope it helpful to others. But another problem I encountered after I have done that,  the execution was hang(the request is blocked) till timeout, I described in another question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46325916/request-is-blocked-in-end-2-end-testing-in-a-webflux-application

Comment: you'd better answer your original question properly or close it if you think it was a typo. Otherwise people will see it as an unresolved question

Comment: @BrianClozel understand it, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I explored the source codes of `mockUser`, it requires a **MockServer** environment to run the tests, but it was run as end 2 end in my sample.

Changed  `mutateWith(mockUser().password("password"))` to `.mutate().filter(basicAuthentication("user", "password")).build()`, the NPE was disappeared.

Hope this helpful for you.

`@Test
    public void deletingPostsWhenUserCredentialsThenForbidden_mutateWith() 
        throws Exception {
        this.rest
            .mutate().filter(basicAuthentication("user", "password")).build()
            .delete()
            .uri("/posts/1")
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().is4xxClientError()
            .expectBody().isEmpty();
    }`

**Updated Source codes**: https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/security-method/src/test/java/com/example/demo/IntegrationTests.java#L118-L127