# Request is blocked in end 2 end testing in a webflux application

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux

Another problem I encountered in end 2 end tests, setting invalid credentials will cause the sent request blocked till it is timeout.

Source codes: https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/security-method/src/test/java/com/example/demo/IntegrationTests.java#L83-L94

```
@Test
public void savingPostsWhenInvalidCredentialsThenUnauthorized() throws Exception {
    this.rest
        .post()
        .uri("/posts")
        .attributes(invalidCredentials())
        .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(Post.builder().title("title test").content("content test").build()))
        .exchange()
        .expectStatus().isUnauthorized()
        .expectBody().isEmpty();
}
```

Another case is if the user does not has permission, also caused the request blocked.

```
@Test
public void deletingPostsWhenUserCredentialsThenForbidden_mutateWith() throws Exception {
    this.rest
        .mutate().filter(basicAuthentication("user", "password")).build()
        .delete()
        .uri("/posts/1")
        .exchange()
        .expectStatus().is4xxClientError()
        .expectBody().isEmpty();
}
```

I am using Reactor Netty as runtime in this sample, the similar tests are passed in the `ApplicationTests`(used `bindToApplicationContext` in a mock environment), and failed in `IntegrationTests`(which used `bindToServer` in end 2 end testing).